# Use hashmap value to replace String get Error

Tags: java, string, replace, hashmap

I have a `String` (`"abc|a&b"`) and I want to replace parts of the `String` with other `String`s. The replacements are stored in a `HashMap<String, String>` and are as follows:

1. `"a"` > `"true"`
2. `"b"` > `"false"`
3. `"abc"` > `"true"`

My result is `"truefalsec|true&false"`, but I need `"true|true&false"`

My code:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    if(expression.contains(entry.getKey()))
        expression = expression.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(expression);
```

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: Sort your keys decreasing by length, then apply them in that order.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String expression = "abc|a&b";

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    map.put("a", "true");
    map.put("abc", "true");
    map.put("b", "false");

    List<String> parts = Arrays.stream(expression.split("\\W+")).filter(map::containsKey)
            .map(map::get).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Queue<String> separators = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(expression.split("\\w+"))
            .stream().filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for(String part : parts){
        result.append(part).append(!separators.isEmpty() ? separators.poll() : "");
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

You could use streams to get all keys from expression then same for the separators -> change what you need and merge whole thing back to String.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you restart the scan for the next replacement, and that you scan for shortest input first.

By scanning for `a` before `abc`, you will never match `abc`, since the `a` has already been replaced by something else, before scanning for `abc`. Sort the parts to scan for by length, longest first, as [commented by rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186521/use-hashmap-value-to-replace-string-get-error#comment81322278_47186521).

By restarting the scan for each input, you may replace the content of a replacement value. E.g. if you scan for `b` before `a`, `b` gets replaced by `false`, but then the `a` in `false` gets replaced by `true`, resulting in `b` begin replaced by `ftruelse`.

To fix the second problem, and to improve performance, you should only scan input once.

The easiest way to scan input once, scanning for one of multiple texts, is to use a regex like `abc|a|b`, i.e. listing the keys separated by `|`, longest keys first.

Assuming the replacement mappings can be anything, you should build the regex dynamically from the `Map`, remembering to quote both the keys and the values in the map, so any special characters won't be treated as a regex special character, e.g. the match-any character `.`.

Here is method (in Java 8) to do all that using a regex replacement loop:

```
public static String replace(String input, Map<String, String> replacementValues) {
    String regex = replacementValues.keySet().stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed()
                                     .thenComparing(Function.identity()))
                   .map(Pattern::quote)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(input.length() + 16);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacementValues.get(m.group())));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "true");
map.put("b", "false");
map.put("abc", "true");
System.out.println(replace("abc|a&b", map));
```

*Output*

`true|true&false`

---

If the scanning should match words, not substrings, change the regex compile to:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b(?:" + regex + ")\\b")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you first replace `a` or `b`. Then not `abc` remains and it doesn't get replaced. You can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and insert the elements in the order you want them to be replaced in. This works, because a `LinkedHashMap` lets you iterate over its values in the order you inserted them in, while a `HashMap` will return them in an order which depends on the keys `hashCode`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("abc", "true");
map.put("a", "true");
map.put("b", "false");

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    expression = expression.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(expression);
```